# Load automatically entity of core data relationship

Tags: ios, core-data

I have two entities A and B between which there is a 1 to n relationship (A-1---n->B). What I want to achieve is that whenever an entity A is recovered is also be automatically retrieved a specific entity B belonging to the relationship. I could think of is to create a subclass of NSManagedObject and modify it to achieve my goal but I do not know how to do that and whether it is the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get XCode to automatically generate an NSManagedObect subclass for you by going to the Editor drop down menu. Once you've generated the subclass, you can write any custom code into the generated subclass but it's often recommended to create a Category as if you need to regenerate the subclass it will wipe said custom code.

As for the retrieving of a specific entity B, you could have another relationship to entity B but this time just a 1 to 1 relationship (say "specialRelationship" for example) and tick the "transient" box (this just means that the data isn't stored in the persistent store, but is determined programmatically). In your Category, you can then write a custom accessor for specialRelationship which will programmatically choose the correct entity B to return.

Comment: your response does not answer my question

Comment: "I could think of is to create a subclass of NSManagedObject and modify it to achieve my goal but I do not know how to do that and whether it is the right solution." - I think I answered that didn't I?

Comment: As for the other part, I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve? Are you wanting a specific entity B with certain attributes to be returned in the result of the fetch request along with entity A?

Comment: I may have poorly explained what i wanted. My goal is that when an entity A is loaded, automatically and transparently loads a specific entity B.

Comment: Okay, I think I might have you now, but just want to check before editing my answer. When you say loaded, I take it you mean fetched from the ManagedObjectContext? And if so, do you want the specific entity B to be, for example, a property of entity A which can be called once the entity A has been fetched?

Comment: I used incorrect term, i meant fetched and yes, I would like that it is a property of antity A

Comment: Answer updated with a suggestion of how you could do this. :-)